# how to disable scroll without using overflow:hidden & position:fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Give me solution to disable scroll of the page. Right now I'm using

```
overflow:hidden
```

or

```
position:fixed
```

I use given code as well:

```
var keys = { 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1 };

function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
    if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
    window.ontouchmove = preventDefault; // mobile
    document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;
    window.onwheel = null;
    window.ontouchmove = null;
    document.onkeydown = null;
}
```

but it is not giving me proper output. My page getting fluctuate when I use above code... I don't want to use any library.

Comment: What's wrong with `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Page contains scroll already. Onclick of any div have to hide scroll. It make page fluctuate.

Comment: Please create a codepen demonstrating your problem. overflow: hidden should be everything you need.
I imagine the issue is that hiding and showing the scrollbar is causing your page to flow differently but would like to be sure

Comment: Create a **[Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)** instead of an off site resource like JSFiddle, CodePen or JSBin when possible. That way no one has to leave the site to see a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0); };
```

Comment: No,   First need to scroll top then only it is disabling... :(